# Cannot print correct answer when I use INT32_MAX

Tags: c++

I tried to solve a DP question. since I need to set a value as a big number, I used INT32_MAX. When I use INT32_MAX, my code return -2147483647. However, if I change INT32_MAX to INF(const int INF = 987654321;) it works. Why I cannot receive correct answer by using INT32_MAX? When I tried to used INT32_MAX I changed every INF value to INT32_MAX.
following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

const int IDX = 110;
const int INF = 987654321;
int maze_size, maze[IDX], cache[IDX];

int JumpToNext(int curr_loc){
    if(curr_loc == maze_size) return 0;
    if(curr_loc > maze_size) return INF;
    int & now = cache[curr_loc];
    if(now != -1) return now;
    now = INF;
    for(int next = 1; next <= maze[curr_loc]; next++){
        now = min(now, JumpToNext(curr_loc + next) + 1);
    }
    return now;
}

int main(void){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL); cout.tie(NULL);
    cin >> maze_size;
    memset(cache, -1, sizeof(cache));
    for(int m = 1; m <= maze_size; m++) cin >> maze[m];
    int ans = JumpToNext(1);
    ans == INF ? cout << -1 : cout << ans;
}
```

test case:

```
10
1 2 0 1 3 2 1 5 4 2
```

correct answer:

```
5
```

Comment: The issue is here `min(now, JumpToNext(curr_loc + next) + 1)` where you could 1 to the INT32_MAX value. You should avoid that as it will result for the number to wrap around and become -1.

Comment: @AlefSin: signed overflow is even UB.

Comment: @skullKim: `const int INF = INT32_MAX - 1;` should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Does `JumpToNext` ever return `INT32_MAX`? Because `INT32_MAX + 1 == INT32_MIN == -2147483647`.

Comment: `INT32_MAX + 1` is even UB with signed overflow.